# What to index on queries with lots of columns in the WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Building a search engine for an apartment site and I'm not sure how to index the `apartments` table.

Example of queries:

- `...WHERE city_id = 1 AND size > 500 AND rooms = 2`
- `...WHERE area_id = 2 AND ad_type = 'agent' AND price BETWEEN 10000 AND 14000`
- `...WHERE area_id = 2 OR area_id = 4 AND published_at > '2016-01-01' AND ad_type = 1`

As you can see, the columns can vary a lot, and the number of columns in the WHERE clause can be up to 10, or possibly even more.

- Should I index all of them?
- Only the most common ones?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest indexing all of them, properties columns usually shouldn't be indexed(like size ,rooms and price). So maybe `(city_id) , (area_id,ad_type)` , but without seeing the data and aiming for a specific `WHERE` , we can't tell you what will be the best . BTW - use `area_id IN(2,4)` and not two ORs

Answer (score 8):

You have to figure out what `WHERE` clauses you are going to use with this query, how often each will occur and and how selective each condition will be.

- Don't index for queries that occur seldom unless you have to.
- Use multicolumn indexes, starting with those columns that will occur in an `=` comparison.
- Concerning the order of columns in a multicolumn index, start with those columns that will be used in a query by themselves (an index can be used for a query with only some of its columns, provided they are at the beginning of the index).
- You might omit columns with low selectivity, like `gender`.

For example, with your above queries, if they are all frequent and all columns are selective, these indexes would be good:

```
... ON apartments (city_id, rooms, size)

... ON apartments (area_id, ad_type, price)

... ON apartments (area_id, ad_type, published_at)
```

These indexes could also be used for `WHERE` clauses with only `area_id` or `city_id` in them.

It is bad to have too many indexes.

If the above method would lead to too many indexes, e.g. because the user can pick arbitrary columns for the `WHERE` clause, it is better to index individual columns or occasionally pairs of columns that regularly go together.

That way PostgreSQL can pick a *bitmap index scan* to combine several indexes for one query. That is less efficient than a regular *index scan*, but usually better than a *sequential scan*.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. Did not know the order of a multicolumn index was important! :)

Answer (score 2):

Postgres **9.6** provides a new extension to address *your conundrum precisely*:

#### [bloom index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/bloom.html)

From the same authors who brought trigram indexes or text search to Postgres (among other things).

A **single** bloom index on all involved columns works well for *any* combination of them in the `WHERE` clause - even if not as well as a separate btree indexes on each column. But a single index is *much* smaller and cheaper to maintain than many indexes. You'll have to weigh costs and benefits.

A bloom index excels for *many* index columns that can be combined in many ways.

I might combine a bloom index as "catch-all" with some tailored multicolumn btree indexes to optimize the most common combinations ([along the guidelines provided by @Laurenz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39567427/939860)) and some single column indexes on the most frequently queried columns.

Some more explanation:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

The feature is new and there are some **important limitations**. Quoting the manual:

> - Only operator classes for `int4` and `text` are included with the module.
> - Only the `=` operator is supported for search. But it is possible to add support for arrays with union and intersection operations in the
>     future.

So not for `published_at`, which looks like a `date` (but you could still extract an EPOCH and index that) and only for equality predicates.

After creating the extension (once per DB):

```
CREATE EXTENSION bloom;
```

Create a bloom index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_bloomidx
ON tbl USING bloom (area_id, city_id, size, rooms, ad_type);  -- many more columns?
```

And some others:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_published_at ON tbl (published_at);
CREATE INDEX tbl_published_at ON tbl (price);
-- some popular combinations...
```

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/bloom.html) has some examples comparing bloom, multicolumn and single-column btree indexes. Very insightful.